# Finding error log related to specific crash in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, x11, crash

Every time I try to start a specific program (Mathematica), my Ubuntu session crashes and I get thrown back to login screen. I want to find out 1) what is it exactly that crashes (probably X) and 2) find the error log produced by this crash.

I tried looking at .xsession-errors file, but the file is huge and I don't know how to find what I'm looking for from there. It would be ideal if I could somehow make X output its error log to another file temporarily or something.

EDIT: The relevant error log was found from /var/log/syslog which says: "gnome-session[3679]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012". This is possibly related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/999191 .

Comment: How are you launching `mathematica`? Have you tried from the command line? Try something like `mathematica 2> error.log` to capture errors.

Comment: Already tried this. No output was produced. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know if they deal with troubleshooting of this sort, but there is a stack exchange site dedicated to mathematica: [mathematica.se]. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: “gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11” only says that the X server crashed and therefore gnome-session lost contact with it. The important part for diagnosis is why X crashed; there may be a relevant log message a few lines further up (e.g. it's the “segfault at … error 7 in nvidia_drv.so” line in the Ubuntu bug you link to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tail -f` to observe the log while you are running the program (Mathematica) and just see what was happening when the program crashed.

```
tail -f /path_to_the_log_file &
```

Start this command in a separate terminal and watch the output there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it seems that nothing is written to ~/.xsession-errors when the crash happens.

Comment: OK, then perhaps you should try some other log files. There is a list of log files in Ubuntu http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/

Comment: `/var/log/messages` could be the appropriate one.

Comment: It looks like /var/log/messages doesn't exist anymore in Ubuntu, but I tried /var/log/Xorg.0.log, but nothing is written in there either during the crash.

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17163/mathematica9-linux-version-crash-how-to-fix-it

Comment: @Echows `/var/log/messages` [seems](http://askubuntu.com/a/51268/85695) to have been merged into `/var/log/syslog` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Nice, now I've finally found something that's probably related to this. This looks serious: "gnome-session[3679]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012". This still doesn't solve my crashing, but since my original question was how to find the relevant error logs related to this problem, I'm going to mark this question as solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior on my machine and it was related to the NVIDIA display driver for my GTX 580. After installing the latest version of the display driver, the issue disappeared.